# How can you retrieve relationsships from a MSSQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, relationship, sql-server-2016

I'm getting data from my MS-SQL 2016 Database. To determine the type of input fields, I need to know if there are any relations set up for any of my retrieved columns. I need this information to switch between input-fields and dropdown-menus.

I've already looked up in microsofts documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) but couldn't find any sys-table containing the information I need. Am I even looking at the right place?

Comment: The `sys.foreign_keys` and `sys.foreign_key_columns` catalog views can be queried to determine foreign key relationships between tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may help.

```
;WITH Relationship
AS(
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY fk.name) as Id,
    CAST(fk.name as NVARCHAR(250)) as RelationName,
    CAST(tr.name as NVARCHAR(250)) as ParentTable,
    CAST((tr.name+'.'+cr.name) as NVARCHAR(250)) as ParentColumn,
    CAST(tp.name as NVARCHAR(250)) as ReferencedTable,
    CAST((tp.name+'.'+cp.name) as NVARCHAR(250)) as ReferencedColumn

FROM 
    sys.foreign_keys fk
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables tp ON fk.parent_object_id = tp.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables tr ON fk.referenced_object_id = tr.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns cp ON fkc.parent_column_id = cp.column_id AND fkc.parent_object_id = cp.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns cr ON fkc.referenced_column_id = cr.column_id AND fkc.referenced_object_id = cr.object_id
--ORDER BY
--    tp.name, cp.column_id
)
SELECT * FROM Relationship
--Where  ParentTable = 'Product' AND
--ReferencedTable='BillOfMaterials'
```

[image]

Comment: why do this as a CTE?

Comment: You can use the inside query only but CTE will help to use WHERE clause. See the last two line (commented) .

Comment: not **only** a CTE, a sub-query would be equally useful.

Comment: Yes. CTE is just syntax so in theory it is just a sub-query.

Comment: A CTE is different syntax to a sub-query. The different syntax will likely result in the MS SQL Engine running the same, optimal query. Its more a question of which is easier to read or which best represents your intent. Its subjective but, I'd suggest there is nothing common about your table expression since you use it only once.

Answer (score 0):

Use following two queries. Replace @schemaName, @tableName and @columnName as shown at the begging of the snippet.

```
DECLARE @schemaName AS SYSNAME= 'put here your schema name';
DECLARE @tableName AS SYSNAME= 'put here your table name';
DECLARE @columnName AS SYSNAME= 'put here your column name';
--The first one
SELECT f.name AS ForeignKey, 
       SCHEMA_NAME(f.SCHEMA_ID) SchemaName, 
       OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS TableName, 
       COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) AS ColumnName, 
       SCHEMA_NAME(o.SCHEMA_ID) ReferenceSchemaName, 
       OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id) AS ReferenceTableName, 
       COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id) AS ReferenceColumnName
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
     INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
     INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON o.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME(o.SCHEMA_ID) = @schemaName
      AND OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id) = @tableName
      AND COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) = @columnName
ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME(f.SCHEMA_ID);
--The second one
SELECT f.name AS ForeignKey, 
       SCHEMA_NAME(f.SCHEMA_ID) SchemaName, 
       OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS TableName, 
       COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) AS ColumnName, 
       SCHEMA_NAME(o.SCHEMA_ID) ReferenceSchemaName, 
       OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id) AS ReferenceTableName, 
       COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id) AS ReferenceColumnName
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
     INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
     INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON o.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(F.PARENT_object_id) = @tableName
      AND SCHEMA_NAME(F.SCHEMA_ID) = @schemaName
      AND COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) = @columnName
ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME(O.SCHEMA_ID), 
         OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id);
```